# Onclick current time in dynamic table

Tags: time, dynamic

I have a table that you can add and delete rows, and the last column is a current time onclick function.  This works for the first row but only updates the first row for each row after that.  What I need is for each row to display the current time on click just like the first.  I have tried to do many searches on this and feel it might have to do with using ID instead of class...maybe?  But nothing i try works.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Time Onclick</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT>
        function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                break;                                     
                }
            }
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }                
                function setStartTime(){
                     document.getElementById('starttime').value = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('it-IT');    
                }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
        <INPUT type="button" value="add row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
    <TABLE id="dataTable">
        <TR>
                    <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
                    <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>
                    <TD><INPUT Id="starttime" onclick="setStartTime()" /></TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```